# How do I extract get money off a local wallet with only the key words?

Tags: multibit, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I am a bit new to BitCoin and as it happened, I just transfered some money into my wallet when I noticed that my client (MultiBit HD) won't let me log into it anymore. Apparently it's a thing since last version that the client sometimes "forgets" a password or whatever. Either way, I have the wallet on my hard drive but can't log into it. I tried to recover it but recovering the password just gets Multibit stuck and recovering the wallet just creates a new, empty wallet, it seems. I still want to get the money off of my wallet I can't log into though. Ideas?
I tried the often suggested method using this site: https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/

If I got this right, I just enter my key words in the "BIP39 Mnemonic" field, set it to the BIP32-tab and set the client to MultiBit HD. After that, it should give me as many addresses that fit as I like with their corresponding private key, which I would then use to import the wallet somewhere and have access to the money, right?
However, I generated 150k results, the address of my faulty wallet wasn't in there and my browser just dies after that. I am trying alternatives now to see if I can get it to work, but if anybody has any ideas?
I mean, I have the physical file of the wallet and the key words...I should be able to extract the private key somehow, right?

Comment: There is no need to generate thousands of addresses if you didn't use that many addresses. You really should see addresses that you have used in the first 20 addresses are generated in the same order.